# Why does this angle calculation return only values of 0 or -1?

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, angle

I am trying to calculate some rough angles on the x-axis from an onboard accelerometer on the light blue bean (https://punchthrough.com/bean/). Issue: Everything I calculate comes back as 0 or -1. So I am obviously either passing something wrong, or converting something wrong. I am unsure what. Thought I would post here to see if anyone has a suggestion. Bean docs say use int16_t but they also sometimes use uint16_t or int. Not sure what to follow. Thanks.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);

}

void loop()
{   

    AccelerationReading currentAccel = Bean.getAcceleration(); 

    float xAng = makeXAngles(currentAccel);
    String stringMaster = String();
    stringMaster = stringMaster + "X-Angle: " + xAng;
    Serial.println(stringMaster);
   Bean.sleep(100);
}


float makeXAngles(AccelerationReading one) {

    float x1 = one.xAxis;
    float y1 = one.yAxis;
    float z1 = one.zAxis;


    float x2 = x1 * x1;
    float y2 = y1 * y1;
    float z2 = z1 * z1;

    float result;
    float accel_angle_x;

    // X-Axis
    result = sqrt(y2+z2);
    result = x1/result;
    accel_angle_x = atan(result);

    // return the x angle
    return accel_angle_x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the minor problems, like use of uninitialized variable here `int y2 = y1 * y2;`,
You are using `int` variables for obviously floating point calculations of the angle, which should be a fractional number in radians (which is hinted by the calculation attempt used). You need to work with float or double precision variables here.

Comment: Alright so I fixed that y2, thank you for seeing that. Then changed things to floats, and it still returns as 0 or -1. I am unsure what a double precision variable is. Example? Link?

Comment: Have you changed the return type as well? (Double precision floating point type is just `double`)

Comment: Yes I changed the return type.

Comment: Sorry. Done. Probably still wrong. Might have something to do w/ The Bean's library. ie: I am not passing something correctly.